# Not able to retrieve the response from the angular js service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

I wrote a angular js service which returns the response. But when I tried to call the service from the controller I am not able to get the exact response.

```
app.service('testservice', function($http){
var details= {};
details.getResponse = function() {
        return $http({
            url: 'send/getdata',
            method: 'GET'
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            this.getdata = data;
            return getdata;
        });
    };
    return details;
```

});

I am using the below controller to call the method.

```
app.controller('testcontroller',[ '$scope', '$http','testService',function($scope, $http,testService) {
        var targetresponse = testService.getResponse();
        alert(JSON.stringify(targetresponse))
  })]);
```

I am getting the below response,
{"$$state":{"status":0,"pending":[[{"promise":{"$$state":{"status":0}}},null,null,null]]}}

Kindly, let me know the error here.

Answer (score 2):

Your `testservice` service `getResponse` method should return a promise, and you can continue that promise chain inside your controller.

**Service**

```
details.getResponse = function() {
    return $http({
        url: 'send/getdata',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(res) {
        this.getdata = res.data;
        return res.data;
    });
};
```

You can use resolve that promise and get access of data inside `.then` function

```
var targetresponse = testService.getResponse();
targetresponse.then(function(data){
   alert(JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Srv.getData().then(function (success) {
        var data = success.data;
        $scope.myData = data;
    }, function (error) {
    });
```

Best way to to this.